# some windows 8 metro (modern UI) apps don't open, but live tiles DO work

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-store-app

Some of my default windows 8 metro (modern UI) apps don't work properly, the apps are the **Weather** and the **News** apps.

when I open them, I only get the loading screen, that is, the big colorful screen with the logo in the center, and the "loading" spinning dots. They just keep like that forever and never actually open.

There are no error messages or anything.

The strange this is that the live tiles for those apps DO work and show current information. current weather for my location (saved before they started failing) and current news.

Both apps did work well in the past, and every other default windows 8 app I've tried work well (both live tiles and the app itself).
Every other non-default apps that I've downloaded still work correctly, so the problem so far is only with those two apps. (**weather and news**).

I really don't know since when exactly they started to fail because I really don't use them (or any metro app) that often, so I can't recall if I did something like installing some other app, either metro or regular, or messed with some drivers, etc.

they simply don't open now, but they DID work before.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, both the apps that you mention rely heavily (I daresay, totally) on the Internet. So, it is possible that they are unable to obtain the data properly and that is why they are stuck. But as you mentioned, live tiles are working - so might not be the network problem.

The simplest solution here is to uninstall and reinstall those apps. You can simply right click the live tile and click uninstall button on the appbar. Then go to the store and search for respective apps. Click install to install those apps back. In most of the cases, this would solve all the app related issues.

**Update:** You mention that

> ...current weather for my location (*saved before they started failing*) and current news.

So, this is how I get it: the live tiles are showing data which was downloaded *before* the app started failing and not the current data. So, it might indeed be a network connection problem. Nonetheless, uninstall-reinstall should solve this.

Comment: No, with "current", I meant real-time (so to speak) information. That is, the tiles DO get updated every once in a while despite the app not opening. that is, the information is not the last the app got, but it is "live" info, or at least is what i can guess with the little info presented. However, I've just uninstall-reinstalled the weather app as you suggested, but it didn't work! now the live tile does nothing, and the app still fails to open.